# Title image is missing ( but is not the WP 3.5 issue )

Tags: images, post-thumbnails, featured-post, wp-title

I use Wp 3.4.2 and Featured Image. After I feel the Title, Alternate Text and publish the post, html code looks like this:

```
<img width="214" height="300" title="" alt="Test" class="frame wp-post-image" src="http://www.website.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/Test-214x300.jpg">
```

Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What do you mean by "not the WP 3.5 issue"? ::: Does this happens right after you "Insert into Post"? ::: [Make sure](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list) the theme or some plugin is not responsible for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this filter

```
add_filter('wp_get_attachment_image_attributes', 'my_img_title', 10, 2);
function my_img_title($attr, $attachment = null){
    $attr['title'] = get_post($attachment->ID)->post_title;
        return $attr;
}
```

It should give the the extra title attribute in the img tag.

You can also use the 'post_thumbnail_html' filter to edit the html output.

ps: here is a similar question:

[Display info from custom fields in all images' HTML](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28657/display-info-from-custom-fields-in-all-images-html)

Comment: Yes, this is the solution. **PROBLEM SOLVED!**

Comment: For **brasofilo**: WP 3.5 has a problem with title images. See this: http://socialmedia101.artizondigital.com/2013/02/get-back-the-image-title-tag-after-wordpress-3-5-update/

Comment: ok great ;-) (maybe you should mark the question solved)

Comment: How to mark a question solved, birgire? I don't know how. :(